# Is it possible to pass in a handlebar expression value to a sub-expression?

Tags: javascript, html, handlebars.js, jsreport

If my parent context has access to a property (index), can I pass it into a subexpression? I can't seem to get it to work. I've confirmed that that with block works with a static value passed to it (1)

```
// Parent template
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
{#child {{../report.ResourceName}}--{{Name}} @data.parentIndex={{@index}} }


// Child template
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
{{parentIndex}} // displays correctly as 2

// does not render
{{#with (lookup report.sections parentIndex)}}
    Rendered: {{name}}
{{/with}}

// renders correctly
{{#with (lookup report.sections 2)}}
    Rendered: {{name}}
{{/with}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you use dynamic data in a child template call (like an index in a each iteration) you have to be careful because things may not work as your expect.

for example when using something like this

```
{{#each report.sections}} 
    {#child child @data.parentIndex={{@index}} }
    <br /> 
{{/each}}
```

what is passed to the actually child template is `"parentIndex": "0 "`, it may not be obvious but when you pass data using `@data.parentIndex` syntax any space matters and since you are using `{#child child @data.parentIndex={{@index}} }` that contains a space (`}`) in the end, then the final value contains that space.

the correct way to pass this should be `{#child child @data.parentIndex={{@index}}}` but this throws a handlebars error because it gets confused by the brackets of the child call syntax.

the way that works is like this:

parent template:

```
{{#each report.sections}} 
    {{{callChild @index}}}
    <br /> 
{{/each}}
```

helpers of parent template:

```
function callChild(parentIndex) {
    return '{#child child @data.parentIndex=' + parentIndex + '}'
}
```

child template:

```
{{parentIndex}}

{{#with (lookup report.sections parentIndex)}}
    Rendered: {{name}}
{{/with}}
```

the reason this works is because we are avoiding handlebars getting confused by the brackets syntax, we do that by constructing the child call dynamically with a helper which in the end gets resolved after handlebars have processed the template.

finally [here](https://playground.jsreport.net/studio/workspace/BJWhmjAeX/52) is a live example of this case

hope it helps you.

Comment: You sir are amazing. I didn't want to bother you guys with my lack of handlebars knowledge. I appreciate this * 100. I had a solution similar to this but I must have had a space somewhere that caused it to not work. Great explanation here that I couldn't find elsewhere.